# How do I get UTM projected areas from a shapefile created in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I create a polygon (or point or line) shapefile in QGIS and it is automatically saved as WGS84 (as I understand, correct me if I'm wrong).  That is fine by me despite being a bit inconvenient.  Then I need the area.  I know that QGIS can generate areas and update the attribute table but it is unclear what the units are and WGS84 units don't readily translate to working area units such as acres.  I messed with this for a while and decided to work in Grass since I didn't know what sort of units I was getting and saving the layer in different CRS designations didn't result in different values in the attribute table.

I try to import the QGIS generated shapefile to Grass so I can reproject it to UTM and I get an error about illegal values.  The Grass environment was created using the QGIS generate file so it seems to me that QGIS is creating incompatible files when I create polygon shapefile.

Does anyone have any insight about this and how I can get legal values from which I can project to my desired projection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From QGIS you can select 'Save As' and specify the output coordinate system. Right click on the layer, select save as and change the coordinate system:
[image]

It is important to set CRS to 'Selected CRS' and not to 'Project CRS'; in a previous post on the subject it was determined that there is a bug in using the project CRS.

However, when you make the shape file you can specify the CRS:
[image]

The default is WGS84 but you can change it *before* it's created to avoid having to modify it later... your area calculations should be in *real* units.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I actually tried that and I get Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

Comment: Are you outside the zone that you're trying to use? Are you trying to use a UTM South in the northern hemisphere?

Comment: No, as far as I know, the project is in WGS and there should not be anything outside of the zone.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not save to a different CRS, your data is probably not in `WGS84 EPSG:4326`.

The coordinate system is designed in degrees, therefore limited to x/y= +/- 180/90.

If your coordinates have bigger values, they are in a projected CRS using meters or feet as units.

Unfortunately, WGS84 Pseudo mercator (used by Google and Openstreetmap) and WGS84 UTM xy are also called WGS84, because they use the same ellipsoid, but projected and with different units.

You can see the extent of your data with `Rightclick -> Properties, Metadata` tab. To change the CRS you can use `Rightclick -> Set CRS for Layer`.