# Cartographic line generalisation plugin error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to use the cartographic line generalisation plugin and am getting the following error:

> "Error: Layer must be in projected coordinate reference system (CRS)!"

Can someone shed some light on what might be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to right-click your line layer, select the `Save As...` option and assign a new projected coordinate system (as described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129467/how-do-i-get-utm-projected-areas-from-a-shape-file-created-in-qgis)).

For example, probably the most commonly used *Geographic Coordinate System* is **WGS 84** (or `EPSG:4326`). If I have shapefile which uses this CRS and it lies within the UK, I would use the `Save As...` option and set the CRS to a *Projected Coordinate System* which would be **OSGB 1936 / British National Grid** (or `EPSG:27700`).

You can then use your converted layer with the plugin.

Comment: What if my shapefile is spread out on the map and not concentrated on one region?

Comment: @darj - Most welcome, glad you solved it! Out of curiosity, how spread out was your map and what CRS did you eventually use?

Comment: Pretty spread out. I have points in the US, Brazil, China, Turkey, etc., so covering most continents. I ended up using EPSG: 3395, WGS 84 / World Mercator. It seems to be the only one that works!